# MaterializeCSS modal is opened without any click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, materialize

I have used the same example from materializecss [modal](http://materializecss.com/modals.html).

The problem here modal is opened before the click event from anchor.

```
<a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Specialization</a>
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div></div>
```

I have added the JavaScript code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
      $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
          dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
          opacity: .5, // Opacity of modal background
          in_duration: 300, // Transition in duration
          out_duration: 200, // Transition out duration
      });
});
```

1st image is where modal opens up before the modal-trigger event
[image: 1st image is where modal opens up before the modal-trigger event]
2nd image on click event of modal-triger

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A bit late on this post, but I wanted to include that you should:

- Be using the latest version of Materialize
- use the `modal()` function to initialize your modal without automatically opening it

From the [documentation](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) for Example:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.modal').modal({
      dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
      opacity: .5, // Opacity of modal background
      inDuration: 300, // Transition in duration
      outDuration: 200, // Transition out duration
      startingTop: '4%', // Starting top style attribute
      endingTop: '10%', // Ending top style attribute
      ready: function(modal, trigger) { // Callback for Modal open. Modal and trigger parameters available.
          alert("Ready");
          console.log(modal, trigger);
      },
     complete: function() { alert('Closed'); } // Callback for Modal close
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce the described problem [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8uvh50m/)

*modal is opened before the click event from anchor*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
    dismissible: true,
    opacity: .5,
    in_duration: 300,
    out_duration: 200,
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Specialization</a>
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unless you have following `$('#modal1').openModal();` in JS file or somewhere in page which opens the modal on page load / DOM ready [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8uvh50m/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modal1').openModal();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Specialization</a>
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have edited my question because i was using for mobile devices i have added image

Comment: In question, Modal HTML markup missing a closing `</div>` is it typo in question or missing in your production code too?

Comment: problem while copying